# JFrame multiple styles

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

There is some standard way to style an JFame (Buttons, etc ...) similar what is done for internationalization with .Properties files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [How to set the look and feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html).

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) for a GUI that can change PLAF at run-time, as well as screenshots of some of the native PLAFs.